# isolated scope function not called (multiple datepickers)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use multiple ui.bootstrap.datepickers on one page and for that I created a directive with isolated scope to manage the open/close state of each datepicker

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tU4KJ0VYffu1LMgtwUZB?p=preview) (the code is cut just to show the problem)

The problem is that the `toggle` function is not called. But when I change to `scope: true`, it starts to work.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.toggle = function() {
  alert('you are in the wrong scope');
}
});

 app.directive('datepicker', function () {

        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            },
           controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.opened = false;
                $scope.toggle = function ($event) {
                    alert('i am not being called');
                    //$event.preventDefault();
                    //$event.stopPropagation();
                    $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;
                };
            },
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'A'
        };
    })
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div datepicker>
      <input type="text" is-open="opened"/>
      <input type=button  ng-click="toggle($event)" value="show datepicker"/>
    </div>
    <input type=button  ng-click="toggle($event)" value="show datepicker"/>
  </body>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSNAuyk5ijLI07b0jDus?p=preview)

In this example you will see that there is a button as a child of the datepicker directive, and one that is not.  I added a toggle function to MainCtrl's scope also.  If you set the directive's scope to true and click the button inside the datepicker, it will fire the toggle belonging to the datepicker.  If you click the other one it will fire the toggle on MainCtrl.  This works because `scope: true` is creating a child scope which is inheriting from the MainCtrl scope.

If you set the directive to `scope: {}`, it will not inherit from MainCtrl and thus will never fire the directive's toggle function.

> scope: true - the directive creates a new child scope that
>   prototypically inherits from the parent scope. If more than one
>   directive (on the same DOM element) requests a new scope, only one new
>   child scope is created. Since we have "normal" prototypal inheritance,
>   this is like ng-include and ng-switch, so be wary of 2-way data
>   binding to parent scope primitives, and child scope hiding/shadowing
>   of parent scope properties.

If you want to use isolate scope and have the function called, you need to make the inputs a part of the directive's template.  Now you have separate scopes and you can access the directive's functions internally.

JS

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {

        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            },
           controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.opened = false;
                $scope.toggle = function ($event) {
                    alert('i am not being called');
                    //$event.preventDefault();
                    //$event.stopPropagation();
                    $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;
                };
            },
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<input type="text" is-open="opened"/><input type=button  ng-click="toggle($event)" value="show datepicker"/>'
        };
    })
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XubXiSgcXJR5KJXeZ8SZ?p=preview)

Comment: I understand your explanation, but I expected that even though I use isolated scope, 'angular' would search for the `toggle` function in the isolated scope and not in the `MainCtrl`. It's a bit strange that I have to use template to be so. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: well..the idea behind isolate is that it is separate.  You don't get any natural crossover.  If you need interaction between scopes you either need to use watch functions or use a different scope type.